# Glassfish4 and Eclipse Neon Cannot bridge runtimes

Tags: eclipse, glassfish-4

I am trying to use glassfish4 with eclipse-neon but when i try to add server it gives me following error. I am new to eclispe so i don't know much about it [Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54QUP.png)

Answer (score 6):

You need to add GlassFish into your runtime first before you create GlassFish server, go eclipse window menu -> preference:

[image]

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced same issue.
Save the server configuration first without deployment artifact. Then on the right click of the server in the server window add artifact.

Comment: Hm,  I did not see the problem correctly  - but if you have a problem with adding an artifact on server creation this above answer will work.